# Como implementar o recurso de 'auto complete' em um JFormattedTextField?

Tags: java, swing

Estou precisando que quando eu digitar no `JFormattedTextField` apareça sugestões de textos. 
Seria possível fazer isso?

Comment: Isso!! Tipo digito o nome prego. Ai vai aparecer: prego com cabeça. Prego sem cabeça etc.

Comment: Achei alguns links 10, acho que é o que precisa!
http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-Components/AutoCompleteTextField.htm https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zAWQ0p27fb0  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=akuNoeQ9WGA

Comment: @MarianaSempe obrigado :)

Answer (score 1):

Olá, utilize o SwingX esse tem uma classe chamada AutoCompleteDecorator

```
JComboBox comboBox = [...];
AutoCompleteDecorator.decorate(comboBox);
List items = [...];

JTextField textField = [...];
AutoCompleteDecorator.decorate(textField, items);

JList list = [...];
JTextField textField = [...];
AutoCompleteDecorator.decorate(list, textField);
```